# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "clients"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, psql

I got the following error:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "clients".

This occurs when I try to execute the following query:

```
SELECT  "folders".* FROM "folders" WHERE (clients.name ilike '%aleena%')  ORDER BY clients.name LIMIT 10):
```

The following code is used for select:

```
  def search_folders
    Folder.where('clients.name ilike :search', search: "%#{@params[:s]}%")
          .references(:clients)
          .order('clients.name')
          .limit(@params[:per] || 10)
  end
```

Comment: Do you have `folders` table in your db? Did you create and run your migrations?

Comment: Yes I have folders table.

Comment: You are using :clients table in the where clause but it doesn't present in the :from

Comment: I use above code for this, please check it:

Comment: Like @AlexanderShlenchack wrote, you try to fetch `folders`, but you're using `clients` columns in your `where` clause.

Comment: In folders table I refer the client_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join your `clients` table in your query:

```
Folder.joins(:client)
      .where('clients.name ilike :search', search: "%#{@params[:s]}%")
      .references(:clients)
      .order('clients.name')
      .limit(@params[:per] || 10)
```